# Connect to a remote PostgreSQL database Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, navicat

I'm new at this and I got a job where I need to connect to a PostgreSQL database, they told me to use this command:

```
psql -h remote_ip -p 54320 -U user -d database
```

I'm trying to connect with Navicat but this error occurs:

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.221.220.67", user "pse", database "pse", SSL off
```

Comment: You have to investigate this yourself: look at the PostgreSQL log, check if you used the correct credentials,... Then edit the question and add the details you found. The way it is, the question is too broad to be answered - there can be so many causes.

Comment: looks like you remote postgresql is only accepting the local connections. Also you need to add your host ip in the remote machine pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Yes, it was only accepting local connections, you were right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not the DBA of this database, and whoever is the DBA forgot to configure the database to let you in.  You will have to have them fix it for you.  Maybe you are supposed to be coming in through a VPN which will change your apparent IP address (although in that case I would think you wouldn't even be able to contact the database without the VPN; as it would be blocked at the firewall).  Or perhaps you are only allowed to connect over SSL, but navicat is not trying to do that for some reason.